# Solution to second order second degree equation $ x^2 (d^2y/dx^2)^2=(dy/dx)^2+1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am unawae of any method that is there to solve such an equation. IT is totaly different from the usual linear differential equation of degree 2. Any Hint as to how to solve.

Comment: It looks strange, but that's not a very good reason to investigate it. Does it come from some real world problem? BTW, if you write it in a more reasonable way as $x^2 y''^2=y'^2+1,$ you'll notice it's a first order equation for $y',$ and not even a very difficult one. You may find a closed-form expression for $y',$ not for $y,$ but that's overrated.

Comment: @ProfessorVector. The solution for $y$ is quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly isn't linear. However, one thing we can do is reduce the order - let $u(x) = y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$, so that $u' = y''$. Then our equation becomes:

$$\begin{eqnarray}x^2u'^2 & = & u^2 + 1 \\
\frac{u'^2}{u^2 + 1} & = & \frac{1}{x^2} \\
\frac{u'}{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}} & = & \frac{1}{x} \end{eqnarray} $$

which is a separable first order equation (although you should also check the conditions, since I took the square root without checking whether to keep the $\pm$ sign in).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from ConMan's answer, we then have $$u_{\pm}=\sinh\left(c\pm\log(x)\right)$$ Using the definition of $\sinh(.)$, we the have $$u_+=\frac 12\left(e^c x-\frac {e^{-c}}x\right)=\frac 12\left(k x-\frac {1}{kx}\right)$$ $$y'_+=u_+\implies y_+=\frac 12\int\left(k x-\frac {1}{kx}\right)\,dx=\frac k4x^2-\frac 1{2k} \log(x)+k'$$ Just do the same for $y_-$